# How to remove the gap between the bar in my barchart with barwidth defined in highcharts

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I'm trying to remove the gaps between the bars in Highcharts with the `{pointWidth: 30}` option defined, using `{pointPadding: 0, groupPadding: 0, borderWidth: 0}` has no effect. (see [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Visualq/6f9yvcan/12/))

How do I achieve the following result without the gaps:
[image: Desired barchrt]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You add an empty series on line 17, that's why there is a gap `series.push({data: [0]}); // empty`

Comment: Perhaps I was a bit vague on the problem, the empty bar is deliberate however, if you check the JSFiddle, there are huge spaces between all the bars and I'd like to be like the picture.

Comment: Do you need to have barwidth?  if you don't define barWidth (ie 30) the high chart seems to draw column without gap after specifiying postitionPadding and positionPlacement

Comment: Yeah, removing the pointWidth does what it needs to do but I do need the point width. (Graphic designer wishes.. ;)) I can make the chart 120 pixels width but than the tooltips will be cut off. There will always be 2 bars 1 empty and 1 total bar.

Comment: Tooltips don't seem cut off when the chart is 120px width: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/9Lztb406/

Answer (score 0):

Highchart does not seems to calulate padding on x-axis after pointWidth is defined. Refer 
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.pointWidth. Not sure if that limitation Highchart.

Although, it not perfect solution, I tried to do using css3 (scss) to position the bar. The solution is quite odd.

Please have a look and hopefully you can come up with better idea than this one.
https://jsfiddle.net/6f9yvcan/105

SCSS

```
$columns-list: 1 3 5 7 9 11 13;
$column-left-offset: 200px;
@each $col in $columns-list {
    $i: index($columns-list, $col);

    $column-left: (30px * $i) + $column-left-offset; 
    .highcharts-series:nth-child(#{$col}) {
      rect {       
       x: $column-left;
      }
    }

    .highcharts-data-labels:nth-child(#{$i}) .highcharts-data-label {
      background-color: red;
      left: ($column-left - 20px) !important;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I like your creativity, but this feels a bit clunky. I'll just remove the bar width and make the graph 120px width and add a container around it with a border bottom..

Comment: Great... removing the `pointWidth` would be the best solution that demands minimal change :D